# How do you send Data from Javascript to Python Flask Application with AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I want to send a variable from localStorage in Javascript to my Flask application.

```
if(localStorage.getItem("current_channel")) {
    alert("in")
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let channel = localStorage.getItem("current_channel")

    request.open("POST", "/current")
    request.send(channel)
}
```

I know that I am meant to send an AJAX request and have attempted to do so in my Javascript code but am unsure what I am meant to do in my Python code.

The variable inside `localStorage.getItem("current_channel")` is declared by this part of javascript code.

```
document.querySelector(".channel-link").addEventListener("click", () => {
    channel=document.querySelector(".channel-link").innerHTML
    alert("You have joined:" + channel)
    localStorage.setItem("current_channel", channel)
});
```

I have tried using `request.get_json()` to access the variable but this is not working as I get the error that `current_channel` is `NoneType`. I have also tried using `request.form.get` to access the sent variable but

```
@app.route("/current", methods=["POST"])
def current():
    current_channel = request.get_json()
    return redirect("/channels" + current_channel)
```

Comment: Is whatever is inside `localStorage.getItem("current_channel")` valid JSON?